# PHP - Update all Fields at the same time AND delete image for each field independently

Tags: php, html, forms, post, pdo

I am currently creating a basic CMS for practice purposes and I can't seem to figure out:

- How to Update all fields at once AND delete (or upload new) images for each independent record

Any help would be appreciated :)

Updating All Fields Code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $sql = "UPDATE services SET page_title=:pageTitle, event_title=:eventTitle, event_content=:eventContent WHERE id=:id";

    foreach ($id as $key => $value) {
        $query = $connect->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindValue(':pageTitle', $_POST['page_title'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(':eventTitle', $_POST['event_title'][$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(':eventContent', $_POST['event_content'][$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(':id', $id[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);


        if ($query->execute()) {
            $message = 'Records updated.';
        } else {
            $message = "Failed to update records. Please contact Administrator.";
        }

    }
}
```

PHP/HTML Code:

```
 <form method="post" action="">

            <?php 
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM services";
                $query = $connect->prepare($sql);
                $query->execute();

                $i = 1;
                while($results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>

                    <?php if ($i === 1) { ?>
                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $results['page_title'] ?>" name="page_title">
                    <?php } ?>

                    <div class="service">
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $results['id'] ?>" name="id[]">
                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $results['event_title'] ?>" name="event_title[]"/>
                        <?php
                            if ($results['event_imgSrc'] == '') { ?>
                                <img src='' style="width:100px; height:100px;">
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo '../'.$results['event_imgSrc'] ?>" name="event_imgSrc">
                            <?php }
                        ?>
                        <input type="file" name="image">
                        <input type="submit" name="del_img" value="Delete Image">
                        <input type="submit" name="upload_new" value="Upload New Image">
                        <textarea name="event_content[]"><?php echo $results['event_content'] ?></textarea>
                    </div>

                <?php $i++; } ?>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"/>
                    <?php if (isset($message)) { ?>
                        <p><?php echo $message ?></p>
                    <?php } ?>
                </form>
```

Comment: Your question is too broad for Stack Overflow. Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Im not necessarily asking for Code, but asking for tips on how to go about doing it

Comment: Asking orf tips is off topic either. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not a forum for a free-form discussion. Only practical questions on certain problems are suitable.  Note that there is nothing wrong with your question per se. It's just ff the line for the site.